# Force disable application autoupdate by blocking network call (in this case, gitkraken)

Tags: gitkraken

Gitkraken autoupdates, and this cannot be turned off in the UI.  This would not be a problem, were it not that I am using it on a managed device that does not trust Gitkraken's code signing.  As a result of this, Gitkraken randomly stops working when restarted until I set aside time to sideload it again.

Is there a way that I can discover how Gitkraken is phoning home to look for updates, so I can block that from happening (e.g., blocking a host in my firewall)?

Working on macOS, if that helps.

Comment: Last week, GitKraken 7.7.0 gets stuck loading loads of git repos - their pro support team told me to install 7.6.0 *every time* because there's no way to disable auto-update. That's ridiculous and terrible SE ethics. Forced updates of desktop software that aren't proprietary web-service clients should be illegal, imo.

Comment: Edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add `127.0.0.1 api.gitkraken.com` then if you want to update to latest version, just comment it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fiddler to monitor your web traffic. I have not used it on macOS, but they offer a cross-os version https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-everywhere

From there you can run a network capture to see all of the network calls gitkraken is making. It looks like gitkraken is making 2 API calls, one to [api.gitkraken.com](http://api.gitkraken.com)  and one to [gloapi.gitkraken.com](http://gloapi.gitkraken.com)

If you wanted to block the updated call, blocking one of these two calls with a firewall rule (or through some other method) should accomplish your goal.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Windows.
Actually the crack work only on gitkraken version 7.5.5.
Install gitkraken 7.5.5 and crack it. After that, go to the directory **" C:\Users\rakot\AppData\Local\gitkraken "** and remove the file **" update "** cause whenever you open gitkraken it execute the update entry.
Execute gitkraken with the file in **" C:\Users\rakot\AppData\Local\gitkraken\app-7.5.5\gitkraken.exe "** (you can create a shortcut of it) beacause all the shortcut created by default won't work.